# Cannot destructure property `allowedHost` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a new react-native project with Expo CLI Quickstart.

expo start --web command is promoting me the below error on macOS.

Cannot destructure property `allowedHost` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

I tried https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5727#issuecomment-533895008 but in vain.

info
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 599.95 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    IDEs:
      Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.10 => 0.59.10 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: Did you try with SDK 35?

Comment: Thanks Oleg ...I tried "expo": "35.0.0" and the error is still the same.           Cannot destructure property `allowedHost` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Comment: look at the temporary solution of robinstraub : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5727

Comment: I tried this earlier

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can update expo cli to  version 3.1.
The latest version.

```
 npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: I installed expo-cli 3.1.2 with node 12.10.0...and this is the error                               Starting Metro Bundler on port 19002.
Tunnel ready.
Cannot destructure property `allowedHost` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

Comment: I noticed this message "Web support in Expo is experimental and subject to breaking changes.Do not use this in production yet. "    may be some of the components are breaking on web mode.

Comment: Yes I think, didn't pay attention for --web in expo start of question

Comment: react native navigation drawer is breaking on web ..It worked fine on device. @Oleg thanks for the response.